# Getting GPS coordinates of a video in camera roll on iphone

Tags: ios, video, gps

I'm trying to get gps coordinates of a video inside the camera roll on ios, I was able to import the video, but I can't seem to find a way to access metadata. I'm fairly certain that video do contain gps coordinates because within Photos app on the iphone you can plot them on a map within "Places" tab.

Any ideas?

Answer (score 3):

I found 2 tools that can do the job:

**1. ffmpeg** 
[Linux static build](https://johnvansickle.com/ffmpeg/), or [Windows static build](https://ffmpeg.zeranoe.com/builds/)

```
ffmpeg -i iphone_video.mov
```

Example outputs (omit some other meta outputs):

```
......
com.apple.quicktime.location.ISO6709: +34.0216-128.1216+151.584/
com.apple.quicktime.make: Apple
com.apple.quicktime.model: iPhone 6s
com.apple.quicktime.software: 11.4.1
com.apple.quicktime.creationdate: 2018-09-22T09:21:33-0700
......
```

**2. ExifTool** [by Phil Harvey](https://sno.phy.queensu.ca/~phil/exiftool/)

```
exiftool -location:all iphone_video.mov
```

Example outputs:

```
GPS Coordinates                 : 34 deg 1' 17.76" N, 128 deg 7' 17.76" W, 151.584 m 
Above Sea Level
GPS Altitude                    : 151.584 m
GPS Altitude Ref                : Above Sea Level
GPS Latitude                    : 33 deg 1' 17.76" N
GPS Longitude                   : 117 deg 7' 17.76" W
GPS Position                    : 33 deg 1' 17.76" N, 117 deg 7' 17.76" W
```

And here's document from Apple: [QuickTime file format specification](https://developer.apple.com/library/archive/documentation/QuickTime/QTFF/Metadata/Metadata.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40000939-CH1-SW36)